# doubt regarding sampling frequencies

Tags: sampling

I have a speech file that was recorded with a sampling frequency of 8kHz. I read the file in Matlab as `[x,fs,nbits]=wavread('speech.wav)`. Now I play the file in Matlab using `soundsc(x,fs)`. But if I use the command `soundsc(x,fs/2)` and `soundsc(x,2*fs)` the speech changes. What is the reason?

Comment: Hint: consider a single tone, e. g. a pure sine wave with 500 kHz. How does the resampled signal at `fs/2` and `2*fs` look like, what's its frequency?

Comment: @guest: Congratulations, You've just discovered how "Alvin and Chipmunks" songs were created - this is most basic pitch-shifting method ;)

Answer (score 3):

The soundsc command will playback $f_s$ samples per second. Playing back at a faster rate than you recorded will increase the pitch of the speech. Playing back at a lower sample rate will reduce the pitch.

If you prefer to think in the frequency domain; all the information is scaled on the frequency axis with relation to the change in $f_s$. Reducing fs squashes the information on the frequency axis and increasing $f_s$ will stretch the information on the frequency axis.